# How to create custom buttons.. like in the attached picture?

Tags: android, layout, button

I want to create android buttons but the look something like the one in picture. [image: facebook status bar]

Normal android buttons are curved and their boarder are not joined... I want my layou

Is there a way to create a layout like this?

Comment: It's not really on topic, but creating buttons like this is so much *easier* than the kind you speak of; just have the solid color go all the way to the edges of the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn any `ImageView` into a button by setting an `onClickListener` on it.

Edit to better answer the question:  The layout you show can be created by putting a bunch of ImageViews in a horizontal LinearLayout.  The LinearLayout has a blue background.  The images that provide the sources for the ImageViews have a transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are just TextViews extensions. You just have to change its background with a xml drawable which has three states